# Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-12.04

I am running an instance of Ubuntu 12.04 on Amazon EC2. I have installed MongoDB following [these instructions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) and [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147135/how-can-i-uninstall-mongodb-and-reinstall-the-latest-version). Following this, the Mongo shell starts OK.

When I execute the following command inside a PHP script, I get the "Class not found" error.

```
try {
    // a new MongoDB connection
    $conn = new Mongo( "mongodb://user:afssagfddsagfdsag@mdb.xyz.com" );
```

I have followed [instructions here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongodb-user/12bfrjs3g6/php-mongo-driver-on-ubuntu-fatal-error-class-mongo-not-found) and created ini file, but problem persists. I have also uninstalled and reinstalled per [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147135/how-can-i-uninstall-mongodb-and-reinstall-the-latest-version), same result. Any help is appreciated.

The error is:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found in...
```

`PHP -i` does not show any entries for Mongo

Comment: Hi Philipp, I have seen the page before but I cannot understand what the solution is. I am following all instructions supplied by Mongo docs on installing current versions of the sw but the problem persists? If I call MongClient (instead of Mongo) I still have the error.

Comment: I actually posted this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22449323/2313887) a few days ago with the full steps to install mongodb, php 5.5 and the driver.