# mongodb and php connectivity

Tags: php, apache, mongodb

I have installed apache and php using source code on my **ubuntu home** folder, and mongodb package from synaptic.
I modified the httpd.conf file so that it will listen on port:5555.
It is working fine and on browser shows msg "It works" for address localhost:5555.
Now I want to make connection between php and mongodb.
How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP cannot find MongoDB driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392530/php-cannot-find-mongodb-driver)

Comment: There is no duplicate PHP. I have installed PHP through only source code and Mongodb through Synaptic package manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you understand you correctly then you have MongoDB installed and running.

Please confirm that by connecting to the MongoDB server using the MongoDB shell.
You can execute the MongoDB shell by running `mongo` from the command line. It will by default connect to localhost at the default port (27017).

```
$ mongo
```

You should see something like this:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
connecting to: test
>
```

To exit the shell type `exit` (and hit enter)

You will need to install the MongoDB PHP driver.

Open up synaptic and search for `php5-mongo` and install it.

Now create a simple PHP script to make sure you can connect to the server, then insert example document and query for it:

```
<?php
$mc = new MongoClient();
$collection = $mc->selectCollection("test", "example");
$collection->insert(array("example" => "data"));
var_dump($collection->findOne());
?>
```

Save the file as test.php, put it into your web directory (`/var/www/` by default), and open `http://localhost:5555/test.php` in your browser

Comment: Solved!! Problem was with php.ini. Php.ini was not at the correct location as shown in the phpinfo() output. I just copied the php.ini to that correct location and it worked.